# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'itervalues'

Tags: python-3.x

why there is attribute error in python 3.
with what can i replace it ?

```
d1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
d2 = {'c':4,'d':5}
def switch(d1,d2):
    dout = {}

    for d1key,d2val in zip(d1,d2.itervalues):
        dout[d1key] = d2val

    return dout

switch(d1,d2)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------


AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'itervalues
```

Comment: use `.values()` instead

Comment: It prints :TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration if .values() is used

Comment: `zip(d1.keys(), d2.values())`